# Separate $_POST array into variables

Tags: php, arrays

I have a Jquery array which gets posted to a PHP page this is an example of one of the arrays

```
array(3) {
  ["updatid"]=>
  string(7) "jammey90"
  ["update_rw"]=>
  string(1) "C"
  ["access"]=>
  array(1) {
    [3]=>
    array(20) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "BP"
      [1]=>
      string(2) "OL"
      [2]=>
      string(0) ""
      [3]=>
      string(0) ""
      [4]=>
      string(0) ""
      [5]=>
      string(0) ""
      [6]=>
      string(0) ""
      [7]=>
      string(0) ""
      [8]=>
      string(0) ""
      [9]=>
      string(0) ""
      [10]=>
      string(0) ""
      [11]=>
      string(0) ""
      [12]=>
      string(0) ""
      [13]=>
      string(0) ""
      [14]=>
      string(0) ""
      [15]=>
      string(0) ""
      [16]=>
      string(0) ""
      [17]=>
      string(0) ""
      [18]=>
      string(0) ""
      [19]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to seperate them into a variables `$userid`, `$rw` and `$access` before I run an Update statement.
I have trying

```
foreach( $_POST as $stuff ) {
    if( is_array( $stuff ) ) {
        foreach( $stuff as $thing ) {
            echo $thing
        }
    } else {
        echo $stuff;
    }
}
```

but in the echo what I get is `jammey90Carrayarray`.
what am I doing wrong?

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('[name="update_user_record"]').unbind('click').click(function() {

         var datapost = {};

         datapost['updatid'] = $(this).parent().parent().find('[name="userid"]').val();
         datapost['update_rw'] = $(this).parent().parent().find('[name="rw"]').val();
         datapost['update_extra'] = $(this).parent().parent().find('[name="extra"]').val();
         datapost['update_access'] = $(this).parent().parent().find('[name="access"]').val();


        $(this).parent().parent().find('input[name^="access"]').each(function(){

            if ( $(this).attr('name').indexOf('O') === -1 ) {
                datapost[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
            }

         });

                $.ajax({
                                type:'POST',
                                url:'update_records.php',
                                data: datapost,
                                                success: function (Response) {
                                       alert(Response);

                                }
                            })



        });


});
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what benefit a loop would have in this case. Generally speaking, you should properly prepare the data being sent during a `POST` so that you don't have to do something like this.

Comment: Why not just use `extract()` ?

Comment: You are going to need a couple more `foreach` to get down in to what I assume is the $access variables...

Comment: @Ohgodwhy no, please! not good to remember register_globals (http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)

Comment: @GuilhermeSehn if you referring to to sql injection or security. I will bind those variables before running the statement

Comment: @Henry it's not about SQL injection. It's about injecting variables in your code. Take a read at the text I sent in the previous comment.

Comment: @Henry I agree, you should explicitly declare permitted POST variables for any endpoint. It will make your code more secure and easier to read.

Comment: @GuilhermeSehn thanks very much for the heads up... I will have a good read though it. Thanks again

Comment: @GuilhermeSehn just read it but it doesn't really provide a solution for me to avoid using $_POST. by reading it i have found some errors which relates to my other project and i need to correct. Thanks again

Comment: @Henry This page actually describes the same security hole you could introduce in your application by using `extract($_POST);`. Anyway, is there any reason not to use `$_POST` directly? Why are you avoiding it?

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte any ideas how to make $_POST more secure? this is one of the issues i am having when having to add bits and pieces to other programms codes some of them didn't do a good job.

Comment: @GuilhermeSehn because I am using jquery, I normally post everything into a `var` and then send it to my php page before doing all the checks, etc. today is my first time in many years having to use `$_POST` directly. I knew it sounded like trouble but didn't know how far it was gonna be. Again thanks for the heads up and the link as well.

Comment: @GuilhermeSehn u said int Magendra answer that `extract($_POST)` is still insecure as well.

Comment: @GuilhermeSehn as i said in the question. I will need to put them in a variable in other to preform my update statement and run other checks...

Comment: @Henry Well, this doesn't seem like a valid reason to avoid using `$_POST` directly. If you sent a POST request via AJAX with the data `{"foo":"bar","baz":"qux"}`, you can get these values in PHP by reading `$_POST['foo']` and `$_POST['baz']`. I still didn't understand why do you want to have something like `$foo` and `$baz` as it would not introduce any kind of protection. Just bind `$_POST['*key*']` in your query.

Comment: @Henry maybe if you provide some more context and code we could find another approach that could help to solve your problem.

Comment: @GuilhermeSehn One last question. I am posting an array using jquery which is stores in `var postdata {}` so I am posting `postdata ` like `type:'POST',
url:'update_records.php',  data: datapost,`. so this will come as array to the php page. I will then need to separate those arrays into variables. I have try `$_POST['access']`, $_POST['userid'], $_POST['rw']` and nothing as posted. I have try `$update = extract ($_POST); $userid = $_POST['updatid']` and nothing was posted as well

Comment: @GuilhermeSehn I have added my jquery code to show how I did the array in jquery.

Comment: @Henry Well, you are populating your JSON object with the keys `update_rw` and `updatid`, not `rw` and `userid`. That's why you can't access `$_POST['rw']` and `$_POST['userid']` in PHP, they simply don't exist. Try `$_POST['update_rw']` and `$_POST['updatid']` instead.

Comment: @GuilhermeSehn its working now but not for the `access`

Answer (score 0):

You need another foreach inside the first one..
Try it and let me know.

```
foreach( $_POST as $stuff ) {
    if( is_array( $stuff ) ) {
        foreach( $stuff as $thing ) {
            foreach( $thing as $t ) {
                echo $t . '<br />';
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo $stuff . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
extract($_POST); //it will separate the all the field names to a varialbles
```

Comment: This is **extremely** insecure. A malicious user could just inject variables in your code sending them through a POST request. This was a feature from PHP in the past and it was removed due to security reasons (http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)

Comment: @Guiiherme Sehn I am just suggesting ...I didn't said that this is secure way like that.

Comment: Well, I can't agree with a suggestion that could open a big security hole in his application. I would appreciate an answer that could bring another approach that is secure.